# Creating a Gantt chart using the data from the Python classes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, gantt-chart

I am trying to create a Gantt chart using the data from the python classes. The classes are as below:

**Stage class:**

```
class Stage:
    id: int
    production_equipment: List[ProductionEquipment] | None = None
    transfer_equipment: List[TransferEquipment] | None = None
```

**Equipment class:**

```
class ProductionEquipment:
    id: int
    norm_mw: Any
    stage: int
    production_tasks: List[ProductionTask] | None = None
```

**Productiontask class:**

```
class ProductionTask:
    id: int
    processingtime: int
    duration: float
    done: bool
    start_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    end_time: int = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    production_equipment: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
    stage: Any = UNASSIGNED_FLAG
```

As it can be seen, ProductionTask is an instance of ProductionEquipment class and ProductionEquipment is an instance of Stage class. In terms of data, I have six equipments , 2 equipments each in a stage and in total 3 stages. I intend to plot a Gantt chart showing time on x axis which is 96 time steps and Equipments on Y axis.I am also attaching an image showing the example.[image]

I tried plotting using barh but unable to do so, as I am also new to python. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please share the code for your `barh` attempt. In general, you should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you checked the [Gantt chart reference](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/) before classifying? The best way to find out is to try out the sample with your dataframe.